# Onchange Radio Button to load Dropdown list by ID and Display in <div>?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have "Country" Dropdown where specific Countries are loaded, & when i Select some country it load radio buttons dynamically (by ajax post method ) ,  and loaded in  & when i click radio button it show specific fields by Id.

I want to populate Dropdown by ID when click on the radio button that already loaded in DIV by Select query by Foreach?

```
<select id="c_id" onchange="RadioValues(this.value)" >
---Select Code Here------</select>

////////////  Function  //////
function RadioValues(c_id){
    ---Country ID Post Code by Ajax Radio.php and load radio button at Radio.php page and load radio buttons here and Post to Index Page . 
if(radio_id == "1")
    {
        $("#fields_A").show();
        $("#fields_B").hide();
In "fields_A" DIV i want to load Drop Down here by ID by clicking Radio button and load drop down  respectively by ID 
========================= =================================================(Field_A) When Click on radio Button BY C_ID                               
   <select id="partner" name="partner" class="form-control" onchange="Partner(this.value)"> 
                        <option>--Select--</option>
                        <?php
                        ///// Here is want to Load Drop Down which coming from the DD. PHP 
                           </select>

===============================DD.PHP
        id = $_POST['c_id'];
        $code =$_POST['DD_code'];

    --> $qry =  --Here i user Select query passing ID
    --> Using while ($rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry ))
    --> Using OPTION tag here and post Select to Index page
```

I just want to load Drop Down on Index Page at field_A DIV ?

Comment: Your question is unreadable. Please click edit, then `[<>]` and create a [mcve]

Comment: Also `$("#fields_A").toggle(radio_id == "1"); $("#fields_B").toggle(radio_id != "1");`

Comment: Dropdown at field_A is not loading at DIV how to load dropdown by ID?                 
                                                                                                                                   
   <select id="dd_id" name="dd_id" onchange="Partner(this.value)"> 
                        <option>--Select--</option>/// here using code for get OPTION from other page ?? how 
                        <?php

Comment: i already used .toggle its working but not able to load dropdown